# Drupal - Views. Setting a filter programmatically

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I hope this is not a stupid question I have been searching for most of the day!

I have a Content Type (Documents) which simply contains a title, file and a category. The category value is required and is 'powered' by Taxonomy.

I now wish to create a view which will display these documents grouped and titled by the taxonomy term.

Using my limited Drupal knowledge I intent to iterate through the relevant terms IDs (using `taxonomy_get_tree($vid)`) and then render each view accordingly.

To do this I have been hoping to use this snippet.

```
view = views_get_view('documents');

$view->set_display($display_id);

$filter = $view->get_item($display_id, 'filter', 'field_dl_category');

$filter['value']['value'] = $filter_value;

$view->set_item($display_id, 'filter', 'field_dl_category', $filter);

$viewsoutput = $view->render();
```

But this is not working; when I query the value of the `$filter` `($view->get_item($display_id, 'filter', 'field_dl_category'))` I get null returned.

Might this be that my filter name is not the same as the CCK field name?

I am using Drupal 7.

Any help much appreciated, I am running out of ideas (and time).

Comment: So, does the "documents" view actually exist? i.e. you had created it from the Views UI?

Comment: Yes Amar the view does exist.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to get this working but I took a slightly different approach.

I changed my view and added the relevant contextual filter and then used this function views_embed_view to get at my required results.

If this helps! this is my solution:

```
$display_id = 'default';
$vid = 7; 
$terms = taxonomy_get_tree($vid);

foreach($terms As $term){    
    $content = views_embed_view('documents', $display_id, $term->tid);

    //now we see if any content has been provided
    if(trim($content) != ''){
        print "<h3>" . $term->name . "</h3>";
        print $content;        
    }
}
```

In my case the trim($content) returns '' with no data as the view template has been edited, this might not be the case for all.

I am a very new Drupal developer so I'm sure there are much better ways of doing this, if so please do post.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to go ahead and assume that you want to show, using Views, a list of *document* nodes grouped by the category that they have been tagged with.

There are two (of maybe more) ways by which you can do this in Views 3:

(a) Choose a display style that allows you to select a Grouping field. (You could try the table style that ships with Views by default). Suppose you have properly related the `node` table to the `taxonomy_term_data` table through a Views relationship, you could choose `taxonomy_term_data.name` as the grouping field.

Note that this *grouping* is done before the view is just rendered. So, your query would just have to select a flat list of (content, tag) pairs.

(b) You could also make use of the Attachment display type to achieve something similar. Show the *used* categories first in a list view clicking on which will show a page (attachment) with all documents tagged in that chosen category.

To understand how to do (a) or (b), turn on the `advanced_help` module (which is not a Views requisite but is recommended) first.

For (a), read the section on *Grouping in styles* i.e. `views/help/style-grouping.html` and
For (b), read the section on *Attachment display* i.e. `views/help/display-attachment.html`

A couple of things about your approach:

(a) It will show all terms from that vocabulary irrespective of whether or not they were used to tag at least one document.

(b) `views_embed_view()` will return NULL even if the currently viewing user does not have access to the view. So, ensure that you catch that case.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative:

```
$view = views_get_view('view_machine_name');
$view->init_display('default');
$view->display_handler->display->display_options['filters']['your_filter_name']['default_value'] = 'your_value';
$view->is_cacheable = FALSE;  
$view->execute();
print $view->render();
```

I know you can probably set this using some convoluted method and obviously that would be better.  But if you just want a quick and dirty straight access without messing around this will get you there.